# What does Islam say about suicide?

Tags: suicide

How does Islam as a religion,view suicide? Is it allowed or prohibited? What sources can you show from Qur'an and Hadith that is related to suicide.

Comment: That's a good question, but I think one needs to define what suicide is first. So to takes one life away because he has nothing to live for then I would say that is suicide. But if you are in a war and fighting and the likely hood is that you will die, is that considered as suicide. Or perhaps another way to look at it is if someone is occupying your house and raping your sisters and torturing your family and the only way you can get rid of them or have some sort of revenge is by blasting a bomb and everyone including you is killed. Is that considered suicide?

Comment: @abushahin I believe he means intentionally killing oneself, under semi-normal circumstances.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Asalamu wa alaikum,

It is forbidden to commit suicide.

> يَـٰٓأَيُّهَا ٱلَّذِينَ ءَامَنُواْ لَا تَأۡڪُلُوٓاْ أَمۡوَٲلَكُم بَيۡنَڪُم بِٱلۡبَـٰطِلِ إِلَّآ أَن تَكُونَ تِجَـٰرَةً عَن تَرَاضٍ۬ مِّنكُمۡ‌ۚ وَلَا تَقۡتُلُوٓاْ أَنفُسَكُمۡ‌ۚ إِنَّ ٱللَّهَ كَانَ بِكُمۡ رَحِيمً۬ا (٢٩) وَمَن يَفۡعَلۡ ذَٲلِكَ عُدۡوَٲنً۬ا وَظُلۡمً۬ا فَسَوۡفَ نُصۡلِيهِ نَارً۬ا‌ۚ وَڪَانَ ذَٲلِكَ عَلَى ٱللَّهِ يَسِيرًا (٣٠)
>
> O ye who believe! Eat not up your property among yourselves in vanities: but let there be amongst you traffic and trade by mutual good-will: nor kill (or destroy) yourselves: for verily Allah hath been to you Most Merciful. (29) If any (one) does that in rancour and injustice,― soon shall We cast him into the Fire: and easy it is for Allah. (30)
>
> > Narrated Thabit bin Ad-Dahhak:
>
> The Prophet said, "Whoever swears by a religion other than Islam, is,
> as he says; and whoever commits suicide with something, will be
> punished with the same thing in the (Hell) Fire; and cursing a
> believer is like murdering him; and whoever accuses a believer of
> disbelief, then it is as if he had killed him."
>
> حَدَّثَنَا مُعَلَّى بْنُ أَسَدٍ، حَدَّثَنَا وُهَيْبٌ، عَنْ أَيُّوبَ،
> عَنْ أَبِي قِلاَبَةَ، عَنْ ثَابِتِ بْنِ الضَّحَّاكِ، قَالَ قَالَ
> النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ مَنْ حَلَفَ بِغَيْرِ مِلَّةِ
> الإِسْلاَمِ فَهْوَ كَمَا قَالَ ـ قَالَ ـ وَمَنْ قَتَلَ نَفْسَهُ
> بِشَىْءٍ عُذِّبَ بِهِ فِي نَارِ جَهَنَّمَ، وَلَعْنُ الْمُؤْمِنِ
> كَقَتْلِهِ، وَمَنْ رَمَى مُؤْمِنًا بِكُفْرٍ فَهْوَ كَقَتْلِهِ ‏"‏‏.‏
>
> Bukari http://sunnah.com/urn/62560

Why would you commit suicide, or harm your body which Allah has blessed you with, it is for forbidden in Islam, and from the above Ayah and Hadith is the proof.

Bonus Hadith:

> Narrated Abu Huraira:
>
> The Prophet said, "Whoever purposely throws himself from a mountain
> and kills himself, will be in the (Hell) Fire falling down into it and
> abiding therein perpetually forever; and whoever drinks poison and
> kills himself with it, he will be carrying his poison in his hand and
> drinking it in the (Hell) Fire wherein he will abide eternally
> forever; and whoever kills himself with an iron weapon, will be
> carrying that weapon in his hand and stabbing his `Abdomen with it in
> the (Hell) Fire wherein he will abide eternally forever."
>
> حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ عَبْدِ الْوَهَّابِ، حَدَّثَنَا خَالِدُ
> بْنُ الْحَارِثِ، حَدَّثَنَا شُعْبَةُ، عَنْ سُلَيْمَانَ، قَالَ سَمِعْتُ
> ذَكْوَانَ، يُحَدِّثُ عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ ـ رضى الله عنه ـ عَنِ
> النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏ "‏ مَنْ تَرَدَّى مِنْ جَبَلٍ
> فَقَتَلَ نَفْسَهُ، فَهْوَ فِي نَارِ جَهَنَّمَ، يَتَرَدَّى فِيهِ
> خَالِدًا مُخَلَّدًا فِيهَا أَبَدًا، وَمَنْ تَحَسَّى سَمًّا فَقَتَلَ
> نَفْسَهُ، فَسَمُّهُ فِي يَدِهِ، يَتَحَسَّاهُ فِي نَارِ جَهَنَّمَ
> خَالِدًا مُخَلَّدًا فِيهَا أَبَدًا، وَمَنْ قَتَلَ نَفْسَهُ
> بِحَدِيدَةٍ، فَحَدِيدَتُهُ فِي يَدِهِ، يَجَأُ بِهَا فِي بَطْنِهِ فِي
> نَارِ جَهَنَّمَ خَالِدًا مُخَلَّدًا فِيهَا أَبَدًا ‏"‏‏.‏

[[Bukari]](http://sunnah.com/urn/54190)

Answer (score 1):

Suicide is prohibited in Islam.

Quran says:

> O you who have believed, do not consume one another's wealth unjustly
>   but only [in lawful] business by mutual consent. **And do not kill
>   yourselves** [or one another]. Indeed, Allah is to you ever Merciful.
>   (29)

- [http://tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/4:29)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer from مجاهد:

> Narrated: Sahl bin Saad Al-Saidi Allah's Messenger (saw) and
>   Al-Mushrikun met each other in a battle and started fighting. When
>   Allah's Apostle (SAW) returned to his camp and when Al-Mushrikun
>   returned to their camp, somebody talked about a man amongst the
>   companions of Allah's Apostle (SAW) who would follow and kill with his
>   sword any Mushrik going alone. He said, "Nobody did his job (i.e.
>   fighting) so properly today as that man." **Allah's Apostle (SAW) said,
>   "indeed, he is amongst the people of the (Hell) Fire."** A man amongst
>   the people said, "I shall accompany him (to watch what he does)" Thus
>   he accompanied him, and wherever he stood, he would stand with him,
>   and wherever he ran, he would run with him. Then the (brave) man got
>   wounded seriously and he hurried to die quickly. So He planted the
>   blade of the sword in the ground directing its sharp end towards his
>   chest between his two breasts. Then he leaned on the sword and killed
>   himself. The other man came to Allah's Apostle (SAW) and said, "I
>   testify that you are Allah's Apostle (SAW)." The Prophet asked, "What
>   has happened?" He replied, "(It is about) the man whom you had
>   described as one of the people of the (Hell) Fire. The people were
>   greatly surprised at what you said, and I said, 'I will find out his
>   reality for you.' So, I came out seeking him. **He got severely wounded,
>   and hastened to die by slanting the blade of his sword in the ground
>   directing its sharp end towards his chest between his two breasts.
>   Then he eased on his sword and killed himself.**" when Allah's Apostle
>   (SAW) said, "A man may seem to the people as if he were practising the
>   deeds of the people of Paradise while in fact he is from the people of
>   the Hell) Fire, another may seem to the people as if he were
>   practising the deeds of the people of Hell (Fire), while in fact he is
>   from the people of Paradise." [Bukhari]

A man who fought courageously will be in the hellfire, why? because he committed suicide just before he died.

Answer (score -1):

Suicide - which means killing oneself - is a major sin and in Islam, it is not permissible for anyone to do it, no matter how difficult the circumstances of the one who wants to commit suicide gets and no matter how bad his or her situation is. The hadith is general in application, and it is not permissible to make exceptions to it without a text from the infallible Revelation.

It was narrated that Abu Hurayrah said: The Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) said: “Whoever throws himself down from a mountain and kills himself will be throwing himself down in the Fire of Hell for ever and ever. Whoever drinks poison and kills himself will be sipping it in the in the Fire of Hell for ever and ever. Whoever kills himself with a piece of iron will have that iron in his hand, thrusting it into his belly in the Fire of Hell for ever and ever.” Narrated by al-Bukhaari (5442) and Muslim (109)

Read more [here](https://www.clearislamicdoubts.com/post/suicide-in-islam-in-order-to-save-one-s-or-family-s-honor-respect-is-it-permissible).