# How can I make dua for a Muslim who committed suicide?

Tags: dua, suicide

I [read](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/325/532) that if a Muslim committed suicide, then that person will enter hell without any question.

How can I make dua for a Muslim brother who committed suicide? (i.e. what are the things that I can ask Allah for him?)

I want to make dua for him, since we were close to each other.

Comment: Relevant: [Funeral prayers for someone who committed suicide](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/44403/20218). A Suicidee is still a Muslim and it is permitted to pray for him. The aqeedah of the Ahlus Sunnah is that only Kufr dooms a person to hell, a Muslim sinner may be forgiven without punishment or may be punished for a finite time and then removed from hell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Allah is the one who decides where His slaves will go, either paradise or hellfire, and what we can do is exercise our best following His guidance, but to His is the final word of where we will go.

Suicide is not Kufr, and who commits suicide is still under the mercy of Allah. You can make dua(supplication) for who committed suicide so that may Allah forgive his sins and turn them deeds in the day after to go to paradise.

[Reference.](http://islamqa.info/en/70363)