# Can you ask Allah for forgiveness for another person?

Tags: dua, death, forgiveness

If there is a person who did a serious sin (like suicide) because of some mental illness. So basically he/she is already dead. So can't ask for forgiveness. But you don't want to see that person in Hellfire. So can Allah forgive Him/Her because of  me praying for Him/Her for forgiveness and Will Allah accept that forgiveness for Him/Her forgive that person and let that person enter in Heaven?

Comment: What should hinder you?

Answer (score 3):

As long as the deceased died believing in Islam, it is permissible and recommended to make dua for them. Doing so is taught in the Quran and Sunnah:

> والذين جاءوا من بعدهم يقولون ربنا اغفر لنا ولإخواننا الذين سبقونا بالإيمان
>
> And those who came after them, saying, Our Lord, forgive us and our brothers who preceded us in faith
>
> <sup>— [Quran 59:10](http://quran.com/59/10)</sup>

> ربنا اغفر لي ولوالدي وللمؤمنين يوم يقوم الحساب
>
> Our Lord, forgive me and my parents and the believers the Day the account is established."
>
> <sup>— [Quran 14:41](http://quran.com/14/41)</sup>

> ‏اللهم اغفر لحينا وميتنا
>
> O Allah! Forgive our living and our deceased.
>
> <sup>— [Abi Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/21/113), [Nasai](https://sunnah.com/nasai:1986), [Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1315660), [Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/10/60)</sup>

Also refer to [Is it permissible to perform funeral prayers for someone who committed suicide?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/44395/is-it-permissible-to-perform-funeral-prayers-for-someone-who-committed-suicide).