# Can suicide be forgiven?

Tags: sin, forgiveness, suicide

When a person kills himself ,he goes to jahannam.
Allah says in the Quran:

> {Surely Allah does not forgive that anything should be associated with Him, and forgives what is besides that to whomsoever He pleases; and whoever associates anything with Allah, he devises indeed a great sin.}
>
> (Quran 4: 48)

So my question is,when a person committed suicide,will Allah forgive him if He wants?

Comment: It is one of the biggest sin. But if Allah wills, he could forgive. But the chance of being forgiven maybe low but there is still possibility. Since it's not shirk.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer

Answer (score 2):

Suicide is a major sin. However it is not Kufr \ Shirk.

While the suicidee has done an act that deserves punishment, his fate is upon Allah and it is not necessary that he will go to Jahannum:

- he can be forgiven through the mercy of Allah:

  > إن الله لا يغفر أن يشرك به ويغفر ما دون ذلك لمن يشاء
  >
  > Indeed, Allah does not forgive association with Him, but He forgives what is less than that for whom He wills.
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 4:48](http://quran.com/4/48)</sup>
- he can be forgiven because of intercession of the Prophet, angels, martyrs, righteous people etc.:

  > ‏شفاعتي لأهل الكبائر من أمتي
  >
  > My intercession will be for those of my people who have committed major sins.
  >
  > <sup>— [Sunan Abi Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/42/144)</sup>
- he may be punished, however this punishment will be finite and he will eventually be forgiven:

  > يخرج من النار من قال لا إله إلا الله وفي قلبه وزن شعيرة من خير
  >
  > Whoever said "None has the right to be worshipped but Allah" and has in his heart good (faith) equal to the weight of a barley grain will be taken out of Hell.
  >
  > <sup>—[Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/2/37)</sup>

---

As for the ahadith which warn of punishment for suicide. The have explained by the scholars as follows:

- They were specific to a certain non-muslim, not a general principle for all people.
- They apply to Kufr, i.e. one who does it while considering it to be lawful.
- They warn of what the rightful punishment is in order to admonish, however this will not necessarily be administered.
- They warn of a prolonged punishment, not an eternal one.

Refer to for example [Fath al-Bari](https://shamela.ws/book/1673/1894#p9).

As for the case of a Muslim who commits suicide, there is hope that he may be forgiven without any punishment, among the evidence for which is the hadith on a suicide during the time of the Prophet:

> أخذ مشاقص له، فقطع بها براجمه، فشخبت يداه حتى مات، فرآه الطفيل بن عمرو في منامه، فرآه وهيئته حسنة، ورآه مغطيا يديه، فقال له: ما صنع بك ربك؟ فقال: غفر لي بهجرتي إلى نبيه صلى الله عليه وسلم ... فقال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم: اللهم وليديه فاغفر
>
> So he took hold of an iron head of an arrow and cut his finger-joints. The blood streamed forth from his hands, till he died.
>
> Tufail son of Amr saw him in a dream. His state was good and he saw him with his hands wrapped.
>
> He (Tufail) said to him: What treatment did your Allah accord to you?
>
> He replied. Allah granted me pardon for my migration to the Apostle (ﷺ).
>
> ...
>
> The Messenger of Allah ﷺ said "O Allah, forgive his hands too."
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/218)</sup>

Also see: [Is it permissible to perform funeral prayers for someone who committed suicide?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/44395/is-it-permissible-to-perform-funeral-prayers-for-someone-who-committed-suicide)